# Compute posterior distribution when many (10) parameters involved

Tags: bayesian, markov-chain-montecarlo

Is it feasible (in terms of computational time) to compute a posterior distribution involving 10 parameters?
The time to calculate the likelihood function is about 1 minute, as likelihood is computed from a model made of more than 100 differential equations.
I assume uniform distribution for each of the ten priors and I assume that they are indepedent.
Which MCMC algorithm would be adapted for this problem?

Comment: The question is vague, because there may be cheap ways of introducing auxiliary or latent variables and hence resorting to data augmentation. It may also be cheap to generate pseudo-observation and use ABC.

Comment: Could you give us more details? Why exactly time to calculate likelihood is 1 minute? Given that no matter if you used optimizer, or MCMC, you'd have to call the likelihood function potentially thousands of times, if it is really so, then it may take a long time to get a result

Comment: @Xi'an Would it be faster with pseudo-observations and ABC?

Comment: It all depends on the model: if generating pseudo-observations and comparing them with actual observations takes one hundredth, say, of computing the likelihood function, then yes ABC would stand above MCMC. Check [D. Wilkinson's entry on ABC](https://darrenjw.wordpress.com/2013/03/31/introduction-to-approximate-bayesian-computation-abc/) or [Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Approximate_Bayesian_computation) if you are unfamiliar with this algorithm.

Comment: @Xi'an: What takes time in my model isn't computing the likelihood function but the step before, run the model in order to get the output that will be used to compute the likelihood. So, I guess in this case ABC won't help, right?

Comment: No it presumably will not but then I do not understand precisely the model. What do you mean by output? Not data I presume.

Comment: My model outputs are the results of my differential equations